# Storing Just the Time in Date Field

Tags: oracle

I have a date field in my table for which I just want to store a time, so I'm doing the following:

```
insert into mytable (timefield) values to_date("13:01:00", "hh24:mi:ss")
```

However, when I query the table later on, I get the data showing up as "2013-08-01 13:01:00"

How can I get rid of the "2013-08-01" portion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you want to represent a time. The trouble is that you're always going to have a date portion on the value.

You could:

```
to_char(my_not_really_a_date_column, 'hh24:mi:ss')
```

Or you could extract the hours, minutes, and seconds individually as integers.

```
extract (hour from my_not_really_a_date_column)
```

Arguably a better method would have been to store the time as an interval: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#autoId18

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
insert into mytable values (TO_DSINTERVAL('0 23:59:59'));
```

or

```
insert into mytable values TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: The OP's problem is not with the insert, but when they query the date column.